# Как перегрузить унарный оператор - с++?

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Как перегрузить унарный оператор - с++?
То-есть оператор, позволяющий меня знак числа

Вот прмер

```
int a = 5;
a = -a;
```

Comment: Только для пользовательского класса. К счастью :)

Comment: @Harry, я понимаю, мне и нужно для пользовательского класса. Просто не могу найти сигнатуру перезрузки

Comment: `type operator-();` Или `type operator-() const;`